# How do I test for distribution uniformity in R?

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I have a dataset that consists of approximately 100 distributions (these represent mixtures of liquids consisting of multiple compounds). I am looking for how to test if these distributions are significantly different from each other. They are not normally distributed. So I guess my question is both and R and a statistics question. By inspection it looks like I have two different groups of liquids, but I am not sure how to do this statistically and in R.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the nist handbook is usually pretty good, perhaps a kruskal-wallis test could be useful http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc41.htm

Comment: By "distribution uniformity" do you actually mean "equality of proportions" rather than "uniform distributions" (which is what it sounds like). Can you describe more clearly what the data are like? Is each observation (what you're calling a distribution) a vector of continuous proportions that add to 100%?

Comment: Morte or less, how many observations do you have from each one of this 100 distributions?  Are these 100 distributions naturally grouped in some way?